# Implement JSON data from API into mat-autocomplete input

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-material-8

I am trying to use Angular Material Component "Highlight the first autocomplete option" onto an input which uses JSON data from an API server (which already works by fetching all the JSON data). Don't know where I am going wrong with this.

I have tried using the Angular Material example but that uses the hardcoding method where I need my data from an API

service.ts

```
import { Appl } from '../intdets';
export class IntdetsService {
  private url = "/assets/IntDet.json";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getName(): Observable<Appl[]> {
    return this.http.get<Appl[]>(this.url);
  }
}


intdets.ts

export class Appl {
    _NAME: string;
}

JSON

{
  "_APPLS": [
    {
     "_NAME": "some string",
    },...]}

component.ts

export class IntdetsComponent implements OnInit {
  public apps = [];
  testCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredTest: Observable<Appl[]>;

  constructor(private _intdetsService: IntdetsService) { 
this.testCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredTest = this.testCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
            startWith(null),
            switchMap(val => { return this.filterTest(val || '' )}));
  }
  filterTest(val: string) {
    return this._intdetsService.getName().pipe(
      map(res => res.filter(s => {
        return s._NAME.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
      }))
    ) 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._intdetsService.getName()
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.apps = data;
          console.log(data);
         });
  }
}

HTML
         <mat-form-field >
            <mat-label>Test Name</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="testCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="autoTest">
            <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoTest="matAutocomplete">
               <mat-option *ngFor="let test of filteredTest | async" [value]="test._APPLS">
               {{test._NAME}}
               </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
         </mat-form-field>
      </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you want, is inside `_APPLS`, so you need to extract that:

```ts
getName(): Observable<Appl[]> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
    map(data => data._APPL as Appl[])
  )
}
```

I would also suggest, that in the service you would store the response in a variable after first fetch. We wouldn't want to overload an api by fetching data on each keystroke. You could do like:

```ts
data = <Appl[]>[];

getName(): Observable<Appl[]> {
 return this.data.length 
   ? of(this.data) 
   : this.http.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
       map(data => { 
         this.data = data._APPL as Appl[]
         return this.data;
       })
     )
}
```

You could also consider adding a `debounceTime` on your form control change.

Comment: Within the .ts file you have created a fake JSON and declared it as const "data". But I can't declare any const as my data is coming from an API server and only uses get method

Comment: Yes, but did you look at the **actual** code I posted in answer. In the demo I just faked a http-request with returning an observable of data in the same structure as yours `return of(data._APPLS as Appl[]);` in stackblitz corresponds your http-request. Also look at my second code snippet in answer, I'd recommend that.